# Get values from dynamic JSON properties C#

Tags: c#, json

I am working on WCF and I want to get record list array date wise and I need array key as the date which has common in record like below:

```
{  
   "EventAppGetAllSessionByCustomerIdResult":{  
      "02/22/2017":[  
         {  
            "SessionDate":"02/22/2017"
         }
      ],
      "08/27/2016":[  
         {  
            "SessionDate":"08/27/2016"
         }
      ],
      "Status":{  
         "Description":"Successfull!",
         "Status":1
      }
   }
}
```

Basically, I want to extract values of `SessionDate`.

Comment: I updated your question to be more generic because i is related to JSON / C# not to WCF directly. Please verify is this correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assumed that you want to extract `"SessionDate"` property from your JSON. I recommend using [JObject.Parse()](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject_Parse.htm) method.

```
JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(json);
var result = (JObject)jObject["EventAppGetAllSessionByCustomerIdResult"];

var dates = new List<string>();
foreach(JProperty prop in result.Properties()) 
{
    if (prop.Name != "Status") 
    {
        var values = jObject["EventAppGetAllSessionByCustomerIdResult"][prop.Name].Values<string>("SessionDate");
        dates.AddRange(values);
    }
}
```

*Little explanation:*

In your case `"02/22/2017"` is property which has an array of objects. Each object has `"SessionDate"` property which holds value. So, following line will extract values from `"SessionDate"` of all objects:

```
var values = jObject["EventAppGetAllSessionByCustomerIdResult"][prop.Name].Values<string>("SessionDate");
```

`values` represents all dates from a single property. In your case, it can be from `"02/22/2017"` or from `"08/27/2016"`.

`dates` will be list of `"SessionDate"` values. Of course, you have to handle possible exceptions by yourself.

Comment: thank you i have changes some code myself it working fine

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure its what you want but try this as your output object:

```
public class Session
{
    public string SessionDate { get; set; }
}
public class Status
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int Code { get; set; }
}
public class EventAppGetAllSessionByCustomerIdResult
{
    public KeyValuePair<string, Session[]>[] EventAppGetAllSessionByCustomerId { get; set; }

    public Status Status { get; set; }
}
```