# Retrieve a value among several json fields if this one is equal to another value of this json

Tags: c#, .net, json

I'm sorry if I'm asking a trivial question but I'm stuck so I'm asking for your help.

I currently have a dynamic json that I receive, and I would like that according to the value of the phone the corresponding field is retrieved.

For exemple in my foreach(var item in jsonResult),

if item["Phone"].Value = "PSTN"( or "UIFN", "TS", "RS", "TF" ) then I would like to retrieve the json field which corresponds with its value, in this case it would be "PSTN".

If anyone has an idea how I can make this happen.

Thank you in advance for your answers and your help.

Comment: Yes, it helped. thank you

Answer (score 2):

I believe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42591947/get-values-from-dynamic-json-properties-c-sharp) post can help you.

Try this code:

```
JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(jsonResult);
var result = (JObject)jObject["put here your top node level"];

foreach(JProperty prop in result.Properties()) 
{
    if (prop.Name == item["Phone"].Value) 
    {
        var values = jObject["put here your top node level"][prop.Name].Values<string>(item["Phone"].Value);
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I used part of this code and it solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this. `thang.json` is a file with json you provided.

```
        var json = File.ReadAllText("thang.json");
        var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);

        if (new[] {"PSTN", "UIFN", "TS", "RS", "TF"}.Contains((string) deserialized.Phone))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(deserialized[(string)deserialized.Phone]);
        }
```